# How to rename files without changing extension in Linux 102221.pdf to 102221_name.pdf

Tags: linux, shell

How to rename files without changing extension in Linux \

102221.pdf to 102221_name.pdf

Comment: Hey Deepak,  I want to use this command in a generic program where files are with various extensions like .pdf .jpg .png etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you want I think:

```
for x in *; do mv "$x" "${x%.*}_name.${x##*.}"; done
```

- `${x%.*}` will give the name of the file without extention
- `${x##*.}` will extract the extentions

Comment: Please try to avoid code-only answers. Take the time to write a few statements on why it works, or what it does.

Comment: Can I use 

UENTITY=${`echo $x | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`%.*}_`date '+%y%m%d''`.${`echo $x | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`##*.} 

 to change the file name and assign to a user defined variable??

Comment: try like this 1st convert it to uppercase upper=`echo $a | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'` then UENITITY=${upper%.*}_`date '+%y%m%d'`.${upper##*.}

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) – how about `for x in *` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```
ls * | sed -r 'p;s/\.pdf$/_name\.pdf/g' | xargs -n2 mv
```

list all the files with `ls` and pipe the output to `sed`. `sed` replaces .pdf with _name.pdf and outputs both the original file name and the new file name to `xargs` with will call `mv` with the 2 parameters.

you can also use the rename command which is simpler

```
 rename 's/\.pdf$/_name\.pdf/g' ./*
```

The regex pattern remains the same though

Comment: Thanks for answer Leon .. but I want to use this in a generic program where files are with various extensions like .pdf .jpg .png etc.

Answer (score 0):

well i am not so good in linux.. but still found a working answer for you.. hope it will solve ur purpose..

check the given link.. you might need a light weighted tool called as **jhead** mainly its to get the header information about the file link created date and time and other.. you can find the information which suits you..

Answer
https://superuser.com/questions/90057/linux-rename-file-but-keep-extension

jhead
http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/

Comment: which OS u having..?? as some OS ships perl compile so if your OS has perl, we can find another approach as well...